# Why won't Ctrl-C complete abbreviations when mapped to Esc?

Tags: key-bindings, abbreviations

I'm running `vim -u NONE -U NONE`, then doing `:inoremap <c-c> <c-[>` (or `:inoremap ^C ^[`, which I understand to be equivalent), and set an abbreviation, `:abb dyca dynamic_cast`.

The problem is that `idyca<ESC>` correctly inserts `dynamic_cast`, while `idyca<C-C>` inserts `dyca`.

I'm able to remap `<c-c>` to the character 'O' to verify that you can correctly remap `<c-c>` but it doesn't seem to allow for rebinding Ctrl-C to Escape.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same behaviour in vim and gvim. I think Vim is checking just for the Escape key, rather than a mapping. At least, that what I think it is after glancing at the Vim source code in `src/edit.c` (`edit()` function, around line 980 onwards), but I'm not 100% sure as it's rather difficult to follow...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `<C-C>` does not trigger of an abbreviation after `:inoremap <C-C> <C-[>`, but if you `:inoremap <C-C> <C-]><C-[>` abbreviations are correctly expanded.